# The effect of channel error on the determinant of transmitted matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, matrices, determinants, coding-theory

Assume the following matrix

$$
E:=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 e_1  & e_2  & \cdots  &  e_{p-1}  & e_{p}\\
 e_{p+1}  & e_{p+2}  & \cdots  &  e_{2p-1}  & e_{2p}  \\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots  &  \vdots &\vdots    \\
 e_{p^2-p+1}  &  e_{p^2-p+2}  &   \cdots  &  e_{p^2-1}  & e_{p^2}
\end{array}
\right)_{p\times p}=(e_{i})\in {\Bbb{R}}^{p \times p}\, .
$$
Let the determinant of  the matrix $E$ is a number like $m$, and suppose $l_i$, $1\leq i \leq p^2$, is the number of decimal 
digits in the $i$th entry of the matrix $E$. Imagine, we are as a sender in a communication system and we want to send the entries 
of the matrix $E$, through a noisy channel. Suppose the channel error probability per decimal symbol is $q$. 
We denote the received matrix $E$, by $\widehat{E}$. Consider, the entries 
of the matrix $\widehat{E}$, are received with $k$ errors, where $2\leq k \leq p^2$. I mean, we have at least two errors. 
 Now, my question it is, with which probability, the determinant of the received matrix $\widehat{E}$ is
equal the $m$, when $k$ entries of the matrix $\widehat{E}$, are received with errors. Notice that, $k$ errors can be 
happen in the ${{p^2}\choose{k}}=\frac{p^2!}{k!\, (p^2-k)!}$ cases in the matrix $\widehat{E}$.

I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: This question is one of the open problems in the decoding process in a new class of coding theory called Fibonacci coding. For more details, please see the following article: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2005.12.054

Comment: This question needs more background/motivation. The abstract of the paper you point to is quite horribly written. The claim of "93.33% correctability" sounds like snake oil, given there is supposedly no redundancy. So you are violating the basic principles of information and coding theory and correcting a vast majority of errors, how exactly?

Comment: @kodlu you right. The article that i mentioned, is not suitable for learning the fibonacci coding.  One of the best source to familiar with code rate and error-correcting capability of Fibonacci coding is the last chapter of the following thesis: http://docdro.id/EZSVY8i